# Prepared statement returning nothing

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm trying to confirm if a user submitted valid credentials.

HTML

```
<form action="assets/php/account/login_user.php" method="post" id="login" class="center">
    <div id="register_errorloc"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="login_username" id="login_username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" name="login_password" id="login_password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="login" id="submit_login" class="btn btn-success form-control"/>
     </div>
</form>
```

PHP

```
$username = trim($_POST['login_username']);
$password = hash('sha512',trim($_POST['login_password']));

//to check if values are correct by myself
echo '<br>' . $username . '<br>' . $password . '<br>';

include_once '../../../assets/php/DB/DBConnect.php';

//check if valid credentials are entered
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE username = ?");
echo $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
echo $stmt->execute();
echo $stmt->store_result();

if($stmt->num_rows == 1){
    echo 'Good Creds';
}else{
    echo 'Bad Creds';
}
```

When I'm doing this it always shows 0 results. When I change the querystring to

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE username = "abc"');
```

I get the result I'm looking for. I'm confused because I'm using the same approach on a different page and it's working like a charm.

Screenshots

[Login form](http://prntscr.com/82t60p)

[Submitted form](http://prntscr.com/82t6ff)

[Row I'm looking for](http://prntscr.com/82t6t7)

**Edit: Added all code.**

**Edit2: Added screenshots**

**Edit3: Added Form HTML**

**Edit4:**

**Nothing is wrong with the form submit. When I'm hardcoding the variable like this:**

```
$username ='abc';
```

**It still doesn't work**

Comment: have you checked that `$username` contains the right value?

Comment: your method failed. another question with misses pieces. do post all relevant code, we can't guess where that variables assigned and coming from.

Comment: @AbcAeffchen I'm 100% certain it does.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Added everything as requested

Comment: I'll bet your form (and input) is failing; that's what we need to see.

Comment: Please ensure you have error reporting enabled. Any issues from the mysqli methods will report warnings.  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: @Fred-ii- added screenshots

Comment: @GianiNoyez he meant the code for the form, not the image.

Comment: @Script47 I realised, fixed it now

Comment: @Script47 I know, I tried to narrow the issue down by just checking 1 parameter.

Comment: @GianiNoyez try using `get_results` instead of `store_results` then use `num_rows`. See if that helps.

Comment: @Script47 tried, but doesn't change a thing :(

Comment: You really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>I'm sorry but you posted screenshots that don't help us.</strike>

In order to avoid further commenting, am submitting the following.

Your form and its related elements may be failing and require a POST method and that name attributes exist for each of them.

I.e.:

```
<form method="post" action="???">
    <input type="text" name="login_username">
...
```

**Edit:**

Try the following, comments are getting too extensive:

```
$check = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE username=?");
    $check->bind_param("s", $username);
    $check->execute();
    $check->store_result(); 
    $row_chqry = $check->num_rows;

if($row_chqry  > 0 ) {

    echo "Exists";

$check->close(); 
$conn->close();

}
```

---

**Edit #2:**

OP posted an answer stating that they were using the same variable for their db connection.

Something I would have spotted right away and causing a conflict, had full code been posted. I've seen that happen quite a few times before, and remember posting answers for them too. As to where they are exactly, it would take some time for me to find them; but I do remember posting answers for related questions.

- *Oh well, problem solved.*

**Solutions:**

- Use a different variable for your username(s).
- Use unique variables.

Comment: Looks like the second screenshot is the output from `echo '<br>' . $username . '<br>' . $password . '<br>';`, so the form does appear to be posting

Comment: added the html as I realised what you were asking

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski yeah... I'm going to further investigate and delete this if I can't. after the fact stuff, wow.

Comment: @GianiNoyez is your entire code used inside the same file, HTML form and PHP/SQL?

Comment: `<form action="assets/php/account/login_user.php"` Brings the POST to a different file where I run the included php.

Comment: @Script47 no errors are thrown and `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);` is at the top of the page.. So I think the reporting is enabled

Comment: @GianiNoyez at this point, I'm thinking that the username exists, but your password combination may be failing. Make sure that the password column is long enough to accommodate the hash and is the correct type. That's all I can think of. check for errors on the query also.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Checked that but it doesn't matter here. I'm not checking for the password in this snippet.

Comment: @Fred-ii- But he is not actually doing anything with password apart from hash'ing it and forgetting it

Comment: @GianiNoyez are you using JS/Ajax on top of that? Your id's suggest it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- No, I'm planning too but no JS or AJAX is added to the project yet.

Comment: @GianiNoyez you say you're using the same approach for a different page. Make sure you're using `mysqli_` to connect with and that you've chosen the right database/table. Also make sure your row itself doesn't already  contain a space. That's what comes to mind now.

Comment: @GianiNoyez replace `$stmt->execute();` with `if(!$stmt->execute()){trigger_error("there was an error....".$conn->error, E_USER_WARNING);}` and echo your query and the username variable. also try removing `echo $stmt->store_result();`

Comment: @Fred-ii- No errors are thrown with you snippet. I removed the `$stmt->store_result();` and nothing changed

Comment: @GianiNoyez do you have any code above the PHP code which you've included? Or thing which might potentially be causing clashes? If so could you post it? It may not seem significant, but it might be helpful.

Comment: @Script47 Nope all code I have is posted here. Damn I wish Teamviewer was an option here.

Comment: @GianiNoyez Last ditch effort. I've seen this happen before. Replace your statement with `if( $stmt->num_rows > 0)`. If that doesn't work, I will have to delete my answer.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Did it and nothing changed. Don't remove your answer though as people might find all posted information interesting when they want to elaborate.

Answer (score -1):

I finally found the error:

When connecting to my DB I use:

```
$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$db = "";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

In my submission script I also use `$username`. Including the DBconnection file caused my local variable (`$username` that I get from the form) to be overwritten with the username found in the DBconnect.

Comment: aaahhhhh see, I would have spotted that right away.

Comment: Had I seen that, I would have told you that there was a conflict in variables/usernames.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm sorry, because it worked on a different page I didn't check the connection.

Comment: I've answered questions like this before and on more than one occasion. Oh well, glad this was resolved.

Comment: *"Special thanks to @Fred-ii"* ...you're welcome ;-)